# Replacing the 113th position in a string with 'X' in DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, replace, db2, db2-zos

I am looking for a solution for replaceing the 113th position within a string.

As of now the only solution that I found was this one, however, it is not a solution because it replaces all spaces with X.

I cannot use the STUFF function or something like that because I am running on DB2 V11.2.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
  REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, SUBSTR(COLUMN_NAME,113,1), 'N')
FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

The result is that all spaces are replaced with N.
However, I just want the 113th position replaced with an 'N', and if the string is not that long, nothing should happen!

Since, as it seems, I have quite an old version of DB2, I have no CHARINDEX, STUFF, or whatsoever function available.

Maybe, someone has an idea how I can change just the character at position 113th?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please specify your exact version of Db2-server and the platform (z/os , i series,  linux / unix/windows/cloud ).

Comment: Its DB2 11.2. So, I was totally wrong with version 10. I am sorry and the environment is a Mainframe.

Comment: please use correct rdbms platform tags when asking for help, in this case db2-zos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:
overlay(column_name,'N', 113, 1)

Comment: Hm, I have an additional question: Something causes me an error when the string is longer than 113 characters. The string has trailing spaces.
The trailing space at position 113 should be filled up with 'N'.

As far I used the following command: OVERLAY (column_name,'N',113,1,,OCTETS) but it always abends with: The data type, length, or vlaue of argument 3 of SYSIBM.OVERLAY is invalid.

Comment: Casting it to CHAR() seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use reg_replace

```
CREATE tABLE test (te CHAR(125))
```

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES('12345678901234567890234567890')
```

```
SELECT SUBSTR(TE,14,1) FROM test
```

| 1 |
| --- |
| 4 |

```
SELECT
  REPLACE(TE, SUBSTR(TE,14,1), 'N')
FROM test;
```

| 1 |
| --- |
| 123N567890123N56789023N567890 |

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
  TE,SUBSTR(TE,14,1), 'N', 13,1,'c' )
      FROM test
```

| 1 |
| --- |
| 1234567890123N567890234567890 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GHACWGXX)